# How do you add html link to PowerShell Report in each row?

Tags: powershell-extensions

I'm trying to add an html link to each row containing a reference to an arbitrary item. Essentially I want to load a custom item, but it not be the same item as the record.

I tested with both `scForm.postRequest` and `scForm.postEvent` but could not get it working. What I have below does not appear to have any response when clicking the link.

As you can see below, the record is "Sample Item 1" but the link points to the "Home" item.

[image: Example Report]

Here is the script I'm working with:

```powershell
# Sample Item 1
$root = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID "{C89D37FF-3919-4D69-9925-943B67BD22D6}"

$items = @($root)
# Home
$id = "{110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}"

$items |
    Show-ListView -Property Name,
        @{Label="ArbitraryItem"; Expression={ 
            "<a href='#' onclick=`"javascript: scForm.postRequest('','','','item:open(id=$id)')`">Show me Home</a>" 
        }}
Close-Window
```

What is the proper syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
scForm.showModalDialog('/sitecore/shell/Applications/Content-Editor?id=$id&amp;vs=1&amp;la=en&amp;fo=$id&amp;sc_content=master&amp;mo=popup', '_blank', 'getBestDialogSize:true;header:Content Editor');
```

```powershell
$items |
    Show-ListView -Property Name,
        @{Label="ArbitraryItem"; Expression={ 
            "<a href='#' onclick=`"javascript: scForm.showModalDialog('/sitecore/shell/Applications/Content-Editor?id=$id&amp;vs=1&amp;la=en&amp;fo=$id&amp;sc_content=master&amp;mo=popup', '_blank', 'getBestDialogSize:true;header:Content Editor');`">Show me Home</a>" 
        }}
Close-Window
```

#### How did I get this?

To get this I opened chrome dev tools and observed network tab.

Your expected behavior happens when you double-click on a ListView item. There will be 3 requests, one of them with `__PARAMETERS:OnDoubleClick`.

Inspect this request and see the response from the server. I obtained json with 3 commands. The one that is interesting for us is the second one (**Eval** command). Inside you will see the js code I pasted at the beginning of my answer ;) (Additionally I replaced hardcoded ID with `$id` variable)